# value_map dictionary in pygeoprocessing

Tags: pygeoprocessing

I am trying to Reclassify raster using

```
pygeoprocessing.geoprocessing.reclassify_raster(
      base_raster_path_band, value_map,
      target_raster_path,gdal.GDT_Int16, 
      target_nodata,values_required=True)
```

in this my input raster is DEM with min and max value of -1024 to 6608 in pixel which i want to reclassify in 3 class (-1024 to 0),(0 to 3000) and (3000 to 6608)
and to replace each pixel value with 1,2 and 3 
how do i make value_map dictionary for this.

Comment: According the documentation `value_map` is a dictionary with source values as keys, and target values as values. It seems that you cannot specify a range of values being mapped to a target value. I would use `raster_calculator`